# vue js - disable nextTick function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

in my scenario i have differents radio buttons groups, when i check one different radio button, the others will be unchecked.
So i used this function inside a method:

```
            function clearRadioGroup(GroupName){
          var ele = document.getElementsByName(GroupName);
            for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
                ele[i].checked = false;
            }
            return;                                                                         
        }
```

apparently it work, but next to this function vue call this one:

```
var nextTick = (function () {
var callbacks = [];
var pending = false;
var timerFunc;

function nextTickHandler () {
 pending = false;
 var copies = callbacks.slice(0);
 callbacks.length = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < copies.length; i++) {
  copies[i]();
}
}
```

when vue go inside this handler the other checkboxes have the same behavior than before...
so i want to ask, there is some way to prevent this behavior? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with normal HTML template:

```
<input type="radio" id="one" value="One" v-model="picked">
<label for="one">One</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="picked">
<label for="two">Two</label>
```

Remember they should have same `v-model` value